# Setting width for display: table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout with display: table and alike, but it seems that display: table-row and others do not respect width property. Is there a way to over come with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a `display:table-row` doesn't have a width.

To resolve, you need to have elements inside there with `display: table-cell` that have widths.

[You can see W3C for a full list of specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html), or...just try to think of it as a `<tr>`, it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `inline` propery for them? Just give them `display:block` css property and then width should be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that table-row elements must be have a width of 100% of the containing table. If you have variable width rows... it wouldn't look much like a table really. You could try setting the width of the table itself, or of the table-cell elements.